# How to use db directory in XMLDOM subset type

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, system, xmldom

As i define note.dtd file in note_dtd_path and point it as &note_dtd_path with SYSTEM identifier, i can get the results what i want

SQL>

define note_dtd_path = "/home/oracle21c/SQL/note.dtd";

```
declare
    doc dbms_xmldom.DOMDocument;
    dt dbms_xmldom.DOMDOCUMENTTYPE;
    n dbms_xmldom.DOMNode;
begin
    doc := dbms_xmldom.newDomDocument('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE note SYSTEM "&note_dtd_path">
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body></body>
</note>
');

    dt := dbms_xmldom.getDoctype(doc);
    dbms_output.put_line ('docType name : ' || dbms_xmldom.getname(dt));
    n := dbms_xmldom.makeNode(dt);
    dbms_output.put_line('systemID : ' || dbms_xmldom.getsystemid(dt));
    dbms_xmldom.freeDocument(doc);
end;
/
```

**docType name : note**
**systemID : /home/oracle21c/SQL/note.dtd**

**PSM completed.**

---

---

## **But, as i created directory in SQLPLUS tool and tried to point the file in right direction, it failed.**

SQL> create  or replace directory DIR288571 as "/home/oracle21c/SQL";
grant read, write on directory DIR288571 to tibero;

```
declare
    doc dbms_xmldom.DOMDocument;
    dt dbms_xmldom.DOMDOCUMENTTYPE;
    n dbms_xmldom.DOMNode;
begin
    doc := dbms_xmldom.newDomDocument('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE note SYSTEM "$DIR288571/note.dtd">
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body></body>
</note>
');

    dt := dbms_xmldom.getDoctype(doc);
    dbms_output.put_line ('docType name : ' || dbms_xmldom.getname(dt));
    n := dbms_xmldom.makeNode(dt);
    dbms_output.put_line('systemID : ' || dbms_xmldom.getsystemid(dt));
    dbms_xmldom.freeDocument(doc);
end;
/
```

**declare
*
ERROR at line 1:`your text`
ORA-31001: Invalid resource handle or path name "/$DIR288571/note.dtd"

ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XMLDOM", line 4703
ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XMLDOM", line 4721
ORA-06512: at line 16
**

**
is there any good method that i can get same results like using define options on the top by using create directory option `**

Comment: Are you trying to embed the Oracle directory object name, or the path that directory object represents (on the database you run this on)? If the latter, do you actually need the directory object for anything else - or could you get the path from your own look-up table, or a package constant, etc.?

Comment: /home/oracle21c/SQL ---> This path is real directory path that i had created on OS(LINUX) and dtd file is also here.    Im testing that  creating directory with path on DB(oracle)  to see if the path is heading for right right file on OS.